# I think this question has been closed by mistake

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

**Original title**: *Can I power my pedals and amp from a single power supply from a single wall outlet?*

**Question asked in the body**: *Is there a product that I can plug into a wall outlet and use to power both pedals and the amp?*

**The reason given for closing**: *Questions seeking recommendations for specific equipment are off-topic, because they are primarily opinion based. **Instead**, describe the required function and setting in which the equipment will be used, and ask what you should look for to achieve that.*

I think the question was actually adhering pretty closely to everything suggested after the *"Instead"*.

*...describe the required function...* --> **Needs to power amps and 2 pedals**

*...and setting in which the equipment will be used...* --> **Only have a single wall outlet; I am based in the US**

*...and ask what you should look for to achieve that* --> **Is there a product that I can plug into a wall outlet and use to power both pedals and the amp?**

Anyway, the answers were good and they solved the problem that I was having; namely, that amps and pedals (often) use cables with different polarity. Should it have been closed earlier, and I would not have gotten the answer I needed.

---

The question in question: [Can I power my pedals and amp from a single power supply from a single wall outlet?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/110754/can-i-power-my-pedals-and-amp-from-a-single-power-supply-from-a-single-wall-outl)

Comment: I've long felt that this section of our guidelines is interpreted differently by just about every member of the community, and it's something that we either need to change or have a discussion about. I personally feel that your question follows our current guidelines and should be re-opened, so I'm curious to see what others think before I strong-arm it back open.

Comment: To me "Is there a product..." puts it very much in the mind set of linking and recommending a product which is what the community doesn't want as it attracts spam and specific equipment can get outdated fast. Remember the close reason focuses on "Questions seeking recommendations for specific equipment " which someone answering the question may link the gear rather than explain the set up. The two answers you have focus much more on set up which is what the goal of question about equipment should be. Maybe editing to focus more on the set up of the title rather than a specific product.

Comment: Also the comment you put on your question today does not help the argument since with the question as worded, that would feel like an answer to it which just links to amazon products for specific recommendations.

Comment: I was a close voter, and my reasoning was similar to Dom's. The "Is there a product..." part of the question made it off-topic for. Had the question been worded "What type/category of devise is needed?" it would at least have been a borderline case. (@Richard FYI)

Comment: Thank you all, Richard for your support and Dom and Aaron for your suggestions (and for adding the link). Yeah, I presume the word "product" is probably what deviates a bit from the guidelines (I re-read them after the close vote). Also, I wasn't entirely sure I should link to Amazon, but I thought that it may help so I went ahead and did it. I may re-edit it; a better title could be _"Why a 1 A power source is not able to power both my pedals and my amp?"_ The answer would be _"because pedals and amp have different polarities"_.

Answer (score 1):

There have been other occasions where people have been confused as to how to deal with these kinds of questions. "describe the required function and setting in which the equipment will be used, and ask what you should look for to achieve that" sounds good in theory, but in reality, "what you should look for to achieve that" might conceivably be answered in different ways -

- A type of product
- One or more technical terms to search for
- A specific product or product line

In many cases, the person asking the question may not know whether what they are looking for is a well-known category of things that can be searched for once they know the 'keyword', or if there's really only one or two products that would do the job, in which case it's very hard to give an answer without mentioning a specific product.

One result of this is that it tends to give the site a bias towards older, 'traditional' instruments which can often be talked about in general terms, and away from newer instruments and production technologies where there might only be one, or a small number of, a particular type of product.

Personally I think the kind of questions in this area that *aren't* a good fit for the site are ones where the asker knows exactly what they need technically, and is looking for open-ended opinions on "what's the best" one - "what tubescreamer clone should I get?"

However, I do think that "is there a product that will do this" should be allowed on the site, on the understanding that the focus of answers should be to give the asker enough information to find the options available to them, rather than guide them towards what might be subjectively the 'best' product available.

Comment: I'm interested in your thoughts on the OP in question, which side of "the line" it falls on in terms of being a good-fit post or not.

Comment: @Aaron I personally think the question is fine in the sense that I think it can be answered sensibly within the format of the site ("you need a PSU with such-and-such a spec - here are some examples; oh and careful of technical details x, y, and z"), but I can see that the way it's worded probably contravenes the current 'letter of the law'. Asking for 'recommendations' can be a close-vote trigger on this site, but sometimes that can be a bit unfair; "I recommend this type of product for your problem" is a different kind of statement to 'I (subjectively) think that product X is the awesomest'.